# Can I pass a javascript variable to inline ASP.NET code?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor

I have found countless examples and posts about passing "code behind" variables to Javascript, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do the opposite.

In my view, I'm trying to dynamically create a Url using an ASP helper class and a variable from javascript.  What I would like to do is something like:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("' + actionname + '", "controller")';
```

... where `actionname` is predetermined by some other logic.  This won't work because I can't break up the inline code like that.

Anybody else tried to do something like this before or have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: That's impossible.  The Javascript variable only exists on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `actionname` is a javascript variable, you cannot do this: the `@Url.Action` method is executed on the server side, before being returned to the client. Thus, the javascript, which is executed on the client, cannot send information into the `@Url.Action` call.

If this is still the case, you could just pass the `actionname` as an arg to an Action that determines where to route it.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot more sense when you think about where the code is executed.

Answer (score 3):

It's messy, but I've sometimes used a `HiddenField` to pass a value.

ASP:

```
<asp:HiddenField id="hfStuff" runat="server" />
```

jQuery:

```
$("#<%= hfStuff.ClientID %>").val("my value");
```

you can then access `hfStuff.Value` from the codebehind.

Like I said, messy, but gets the job done sometimes.